# Display text while Page is loading in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, user-experience

I have a page that is quite heavy and its loading for about 1-2 sec after click. During this time I see loading page header and old page content, it looks so irresponsive. All I want to achive is to display temporary Label with content like "Loading..." or activityindicator as long as new page is loading but I have no idea how to do this. What is the better way to achive this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide complete details including the code that you used to navigate to other page and the code you are executing on the other pages Load. Help us understanding your problem. Because particular problem you are asking might need us to check your code in multiple places.

Comment: I am just using Navigiation.PushAsync(new MyNewPage()), where MyNewPage is loading quite long (it doesnt matter) and I want to display preview with Label  while this page is loading.

Comment: You page is loading data from WebService ? or Other heavy UI ? They are all Async? Are you using MVVM ?

Comment: Loading data from api (async) and quite heavy UI and yes I am using MVVM.

Comment: Have you been able to find any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, you just want to display Busy indicator while you are loading the Data from your Api. You didn't posted your UI but I hope you understand how to use the below:

```
<Grid>
     <YOUR-UI>
         .....
         .........
     </YOUR-UI>

     <ActivityIndicator VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
</Grid>
```

In your ViewModel, Add IsBusy Property as below:

```
private bool _isBusy;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get{return _isBusy;}
    set { _isBusy=value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Then when you are Calling the API to load your Data do something like:

```
public async void LoadDataFromApi()
{
    IsBusy=true;  //Show the Indicator
    var response= await YourService.Method();  //this is where you calling your api
    //do other stuffs if you need to do;
    IsBusy=false;   //Hide the Indicator
}
```

Let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have few images on my Page. Loading them last so long (I just  checked it). I would like to display label loading untill all images will be loaded. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Oh! So you want to display the Placeholder in the Image while the Image is being downloaded ? But you said, you have your BackEnd API that needs to be run longer while showing indicator !

Comment: I would rather display something like this untill all images will be loaded, https://ibb.co/X2FYjr9

Comment: @BartekChyży In that case, replace the `ActivityIndicator` with a `Label`, and make it centre screen.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments on other answer - instead of ActivityIndicator - you could use a simple frame that covers all the layout and make it visible only when data are loading i.e. Binding `IsVisible` to `IsBusy` property. Then set `IsBusy` to true before doing the heavy load job and set back to false afterwards as shown in previous answer.

For instance, assuming your UI is based on a Grid layout (in this example 3 rows/2 columns):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Some XAML for the grid content -->

    <!-- Here, Frame covers all the possible space defined using RowSpan/ColumnSpan -->
    <Frame Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" BackgroundColor="LightGray">
       <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Loading Samples..." />
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

[image: See result]

### -------------------------------------------------

### EDIT based on OP comments:

Bases on the code you provided (better paste it in SO next time ;)), you could try this:

Add a grid layout and a frame to the xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Namespace"    
             xmlns:tabView="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.TabView;assembly=Syncfusion.SfTabView.XForms"
             xmlns:sfPopup="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.PopupLayout;assembly=Syncfusion.SfPopupLayout.XForms" 
             BackgroundColor="#d4d4d4">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="search_white_90.png"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <tabView:SfTabView x:Name="ProductsTabView" VisibleHeaderCount="3" TabHeaderBackgroundColor="#A74B40" Items="{Binding}">
                <tabView:SfTabView.SelectionIndicatorSettings>
                    <tabView:SelectionIndicatorSettings
                        Color="#fff" StrokeThickness="3"/>
                </tabView:SfTabView.SelectionIndicatorSettings>
            </tabView:SfTabView>
            <Frame x:Name="theFrame" BackgroundColor="White">
               <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Loading Samples..." />
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

`ProductsTabView` and `theFrame` will cover the same space on screen and frame will be available in code behind. Then you can show/hide theFrame before/afrer the hard work using `IsVisible` property:

```
public partial class ProviderPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ProviderPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            theFrame.IsVisible = true; // Show the Frame on top of tabView
            ProductsTabView.Items = GetTabItemCollection();    
            theFrame.IsVisible = false; // Hide the Frame
        }
        ...
```

As a side note, you don't use `ViewModel` at all. I strongly recommand you to check about what a ViewModel is and how to use them with MVVM pattern. It will make your life easier in the long run using `Binding`!

HIH & Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for response! Unfortunetely I still have to wait till the page is fully loaded (during this time I see old Page Content) and the frame doesnt appear.  I Have constructor like: Ctor()
{
InitializeComponent();
this.IsBusy=true;
BindingContext = this;
MyHeavyTabbedView.Source = GetHeavySource();
this.IsBusy = false;
}

Comment: Maybe sould I do something like: GoToNextPage(){
this.LoadingFrame.IsVisible = true:
await Navigation.PushAsync(new HeavyPage())
this.LoadingFrame.IsVisible=false
}

In page that push my heavy page?

Comment: It works fine for second time, but it still dosnt work for first loading. The page have few heavy images that are loading quite long , for second time those images are stored in cache so it works fine (I think images couse this but I am not sure). Do you have any idea how to achive it for first loading too?

Comment: pastebin.com/se0fhmyQ I want to display ActivityInicator or simple page with label untill ProvidersPage as long as this page with all images is loaded

Comment: Just to make sure, is it `GetTabItemCollection();` that takes time?

Comment: For now it just returns predefined object. (No internet connection)

Comment: I know in this example MVVM is not used it is just exmple code to show the problem. I did everything you wrote and I am getting same result. Frame doesn't appear. I still have to wati for whole SfTabbedView, Do you have any idea? Thank you for your time

Comment: Maybe I shoud try to display this in calling page? I mean display it before navigation.pushasync()

Comment: Strange... Since `Frame` is added as last element into the grid, it should be already visible on top of the `TabView`. Maybe force it in Xaml file like this `<Frame x:Name="theFrame" BackgroundColor="White" IsVisible="True">`

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs, It's make you easily to implement loading

for example:

```
 using (this.Dialogs.Loading("Loading text"))
    {
         //Do something i.e: await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
```

OR

```
this.Dialogs.ShowLoading("Loading text");
//Do something i.e: await Task.Delay(3000);
this.Dialogs.HideLoading();
```

OR
https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/src/Samples/Samples/ViewModels/ProgressViewModel.cs

Answer (score 0):

I have a project for advanced page transitions in Xamarin.Forms that may help you. Try this:

1. Install this nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Segues (it is currently only prerelease, so you'll need to check the box to see it)
2. Add this sample to your project: https://github.com/chkn/Xamarin.Forms.Segues/blob/master/Sample/Shared/Custom%20Segues/SpinnerSegue.cs
3. In the `DoWork` method of `SpinnerSegue` add the code to load the data.
4. In your code that navigates to the other page, replace `Navigiation.PushAsync(new MyNewPage())` with `new SpinnerSegue().ExecuteAsync(this, new MyNewPage())`